# provisioning using SCIM

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim

Does Azure AD has a mechanism to detect if the target system is down during SCIM synch? For example a user is added to AD and this user has to be provisioned to some other target system that also supports SCIM, however the target system is down due to whatever reason. Can Azure AD detects once the target system is up so the changes can be synched with the target system?

Comment: Maybe you can use [Microsoft intune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/what-is-intune) to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be marked as process escrow and it will retry exporting later:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/check-status-user-account-provisioning

- Process escrow events - Process escrows occur when the provisioning service encounters a failure while attempting an operation, and begins to retry the operation on a back-off interval of time. An "escrow" event is recorded each time a provisioning operation was retired.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD will postpone the sync for some time and retry. For this reason it's mandatory to check the Audit Logs once in a while to make sure to detect and correct errors.